# Access dynamic variable names in for loop

Tags: javascript

I have a basic problem with for loop "tostring" iteration.

Description:

1. There are 12 `<input type="text">` containers.
2. I want to detect when user writes `si` word in any 3 out of 12 containers.
3. If user types `si` exactly 3 times I set an alert called `You made it!`.

Problem:

1. Most likely that line is incorrect: `if(cube[i].includes("si"))`.
2. Not sure how to check all containers in for loop just to count the number of `si` word. (adding number to string in for loop to call another variables e.g. cube1, cube2, cube3 etc.)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you :)

```
function transmute() {
  var cube1 = document.getElementById("cube_slot1").value;
  var cube2 = document.getElementById("cube_slot2").value;
  var cube3 = document.getElementById("cube_slot3").value;
  var cube4 = document.getElementById("cube_slot4").value;
  var cube5 = document.getElementById("cube_slot5").value;
  var cube6 = document.getElementById("cube_slot6").value;
  var cube7 = document.getElementById("cube_slot7").value;
  var cube8 = document.getElementById("cube_slot8").value;
  var cube9 = document.getElementById("cube_slot9").value;
  var cube10 = document.getElementById("cube_slot10").value;
  var cube11 = document.getElementById("cube_slot11").value;
  var cube12 = document.getElementById("cube_slot12").value;
  var counter = 0;

  for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    if (cube[i].includes("si")) {
      counter += 1;
    }
  }
  if (counter == 3) {
    alert("You made it!");
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have an array called `cube`, which is what `cube[i]` is trying to access. Use an array instead of 12 separate variables!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could simplify your approach, but iterating over your elements within a for loop (via a dynamic `id`), and counting occasions where the `si` substring is found in input values.

If three or more cases are encountered, display the alert() and then break early from the loop:

```js
function transmute() {
  
  for(var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {

    var id = 'cube_slot' + i;
    var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
    
    if(value.includes('si')) {
      counter += 1;      
    }

    if(counter >= 3) {
      alert("You made it!");
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe giving a class to all the elements would make it easier using getElementsByClassName()

Comment: @PabloMáximo yes, that would be an ideal approach if a common class were defined in the markup

Comment: You can also use queryselectorall: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll and loop through each element in the return

Comment: @Dacre Denny Much more elegant approach and works as well. Thank you so much for teaching me.

Comment: @stacho163 you're welcome, glad I could help - please consider accepting this answer (by clicking the white arrow) if you have found it helpful :-)